# Let $[0,\omega_1)$ be the set of all countable ordinals with the order topology. Prove that $[0,\omega_1)$ is star-Rothberger.

Tags: general-topology

A space $X$ is said to be star-Rothberger if for each sequence $(\mathcal{U}_n)$ of open covers of $X$ there exists a sequence $(U_n)$ such that for each $n$ $U_n\in\mathcal{U}_n$ and $\{St(U_n,\mathcal{U}_n) : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is an open cover of $X$.

Comment: Posted also on MO: [Let $[0,\omega_1)$ be the set of all countable ordinals with the order topology. Prove that $[0,\omega_1)$ is star-Rothberger](https://mathoverflow.net/q/383053).

Answer (score 4):

HINT: Let $X=[0,\omega_1)$. Use the [pressing-down lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fodor%27s_lemma) to show that if $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of $[0,\omega_1)$, then there is an $\alpha\in X$ such that

$$\bigcup\{U\in\mathscr{U}:\alpha\in U\}\supseteq[\alpha,\omega_1)\,,$$

and conclude that there is a $U\in\mathscr{U}$ such that $\operatorname{st}(U,\mathscr{U})\supseteq(\alpha,\omega_1]$ and hence $X\setminus\operatorname{st}(U,\mathscr{U})$ is compact.

Comment: Nice! Do you know whether $[0,\omega_1)$ is "plain old" Rothberger too ? Or does the extra star make this big a difference? There seem to be lots of minute variations on these selection properties...

Comment: @Henno: I don’t know off the top of my head; to be honest, I think that this is only the second time that I’ve encountered the notion of a Rothberger space at all!

Comment: @Henno: No, it’s not. Take each $\mathscr{U}_n$ to be the cover of by open proper initial segments; if $U_n\in\mathscr{U}_n$ for each $n\in\omega$, then $\bigcup_nU_n$ is countable.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott: If you give a sketch of the proof, it will be a great help for me.